# Removing parent of item's collection in Entity Framework DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

I'm trying to remove a Group object from database (created by EF CodeFirst) and it works perfectly when collection Items is empty. If it's not empty, i have DbUpdateException. What's wrong with this code?

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("OptionalParent")]
    public int? OptionalParentId { get; set; }
    public OptionalParent OptionalParent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RequiredParent")]
    public int RequiredParentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public RequiredParent RequiredParent { get; set; }

    List<Item> items = null;

    public List<Item> Items // works fine only when this list is empty
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Group")]
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public  Group Group{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RequiredParent")] // might be the same entity as Group's RequiredParent
    public int RequiredParentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public  RequiredParent RequiredParent{ get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to remove Group like this:

```
using (var ctx = new ZoltarApp.Database.DatabaseContext())
{
    ctx.Groups.Attach(group);
    ctx.Groups.Remove(group);
}
```

**I don't want to cascade delete Items when Group is removed.**

EDIT: I still didn't resolve this problem. Is there anyone who knows the answer?

Comment: What does the update-exception say?

Comment: If you don't update the items (loading in the context should be enough) then they will have a value for `GroupId` that doesn't refer to an actual Group record. Database integrity will complain.